# How get data from outer database in zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

Can I get data from outer database through zabbix?
I have outer database of my service and in zabbix I need get some data from this database.
This is possible?

Comment: I have no idea what you want. Do you want to query the zabbix database or do you want to query an other database with zabbix?

Comment: I want to query an other database with zabbix

Comment: Which zabbix version? From some v5 release on zabbix can use odbc to query databases. If you don’t like odbc use https://GitHub.com/ikzelf/zbxdb that I wrote during v2 and is still up-to-date.

Comment: zabbix ver. 6.0.4
I'm more interested in whether zabbix can make direct queries to external databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible to read a database using zabbix. See [Out-of-the-box database monitoring](https://blog.zabbix.com/out-of-the-box-database-monitoring/13957/)
An other option is to use [zbxdb](https://github.com/ikzelf/zbxdb) that I wrote and still maintain. To be successful you need to have some knowledge of zabbix, the database you want to query and when using ODBC, how to configure ODBC. zbxdb uses native drivers.

Don't forget that Zabbix is a monitoring tool. So your queries will normally deliver key/value pairs and not just rows.